# SVN importing a file

Tags: svn, copy

I am trying to copy a ZIP File to SVN server. I dont want to version the file. It is just a binary for my tag.
I'm using this command.

svn import "D:\Projetos\Stoneage\BFS\trunk\release\BFS_2015.zip" "https://10.20.43.53:8556/svn/StoneAge/Engenharia de Software/BFS/tag/2015/release/BFS_2015.zip" -m "test"

The CMD don't show any errors. And the file isnt imported to destination folder.

Am i using the right command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn import` is used to import directories. For a single file use `svn add`, than `svn commit`. There isn't an option to put a file to a repository without versioning it.